# sed find replace using bash arrays fails

Tags: bash, sed

I have three files, two files with 2259 IP addresses in each file.  One file with 137772.  The script uses sed with bash arrays and a for loop to replace the IPs in an access.log with different IPs. After several hours of running the script fails with this error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

The number of uniq IP addresses is also short by six IPs.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
_ORGIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
_alIPs=($(<access.log.IPs)
_fIPs=($(<randomIPs.txt)
for (( _i=1; _i<=2259; _i++ ))
do 
  sed -i "s/${_alIPs[$_i]}/${_fIPs[$_i]}/g" access.log
done
IFS=$_ORGIFS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices in bash start at 0. When you say

```
for (( _i=1; _i<=2259; _i++ ))
```

you ignore the first entry and go one past the end, at which point

```
sed -i "s/${_alIPs[$_i]}/${_fIPs[$_i]}/g" access.log
```

expands to

```
sed -i "s//something/g" access.log
```

The `//` in the `s` command attempts to reuse the previously used regular expression, which doesn't exist, and so you get the error.

The solution is to use

```
for (( _i=0; _i<2259; _i++ ))
```

...although, seriously, I'd spend some time thinking about ways to do those replacements in bulk.

**Addendum:** Such as

```
sed -i -f <(paste access.log.IPs randomIPs.txt | awk '{ print "s/" $1 "/" $2 "/g" }') access.log
```

(assuming I read your intentions correctly)

Comment: Or, just use awk instead of sed with a process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

this is taken from my own bash template lib use as needed:

```
# parse a template and return it
# 1st arg is template tags [array]
# 2nd arg is replacement values for template tags [array]
# 3rd arg is template file path
# usage: TT=$(parseTemplate TAGS[@] REPLACE[@] $MAIL_TEMPLATE); echo $TT;
function parseTemplate()
{
    local _TAG=("${!1}")
    local _REPLACE=("${!2}")
    local _TEMPLATE="${3}"
    local _PATTERN=""
    local i

    if [[ ${#_TAG[@]} > 0 ]]; then
        _PATTERN="-e s#\%\%${_TAG[0]}\%\%#${_REPLACE[0]}#g"
        for (( i = 1 ; i < ${#_TAG[@]} ; i++ ))
        do
            _PATTERN="${_PATTERN}; s#\%\%${_TAG[${i}]}\%\%#${_REPLACE[${i}]}#g"
        done

        local SED=`which sed`
        $SED "${_PATTERN}" < "${_TEMPLATE}"
    else
        local CAT=`which cat`
        $CAT "${_TEMPLATE}"
    fi
}
```

The template replacement tags have this format: `%%TAG%%` one can change this, but this is what this function uses

Example template (file or text):

```
Hello %%NAME%%, your location is %%LOCATION%%


TAGS = ('NAME' 'LOCATION');
REPLACE = ('Nikos' 'GR')
TT=$(parseTemplate TAGS[@] REPLACE[@] $MAIL_TEMPLATE); 
echo $TT;
```

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

Comment: ``SED=`which sed`; $SED ...`` offers no advantage to just calling `command sed  ...`

Comment: @glennjackman, ok, this is just taking care of some extreme situations where the command is not in the /bin path (in various environments), one can easily remove these extra code