# Replace bash variables in template file

Tags: linux, bash

I am attempting to use Bash in order to run a form of an install process. During this process, a configuration file is copied and certain values are replaced inside of it. Such a config can be found below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root ${INSTALLPATH};
    server_name ${SITEURL};

    client_max_body_size 20m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    location / {
        try_files /public/router.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass ${PHPSERV};
        fastcgi_index router.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /assets {
        try_files /app/$uri =404;
    }

}

#Enables HTTPS access
#This requires you to install certificates and is not enabled by default
#If you wish to enable HTTPS, uncomment (remove the #s) from the below lines
#And change the ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key to point to the     correct
#certificates.

#server {
#    listen 443;
#    root ${INSTALLPATH};
#    server_name ${SITEURL};
#
#    ssl on;
#    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/site.crt;
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site.key;
#
#    location / {
#        try_files /public/router.php =404;
#        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
#        fastcgi_pass ${PHPSERV};
#        fastcgi_index router.php;
#        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
#        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
#    }
#
#    location /assets {
#        try_files /app/$uri =404;
#    }
#
#}
```

I have been finding that most examples stem off the use of eval, and I have tried using that to do this replacement, however it appears that the file here does not properly expand, and bash tries to execute some stuff and can't.

Currently, I have this

```
INSTALLPATH="/var/www/html/mycustomsite/"
PHPSERV="127.0.0.1:9000"
SITEURL="example.com"

while read -r line; do
    eval echo -e "${line}"
done < template
```

However, this does not properly replace the values that are declared, nor does it generate the file correctly. It loses for example any line that starts with # and tries to execute others (along with losing some spacing).

What would be the correct way to do this, using just Bash and commands available on most Linux systems?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487986/sed-find-replace-using-bash-arrays-fails/29488120#29488120

Comment: Dynamically is what I was partly going for, since I would like to avoid editing that replacement code as little as possible in futures, but that would fit what I am needing

Comment: you can adapt the template tag format easily, this is what is used by default but easily changed in one line

Comment: i find it best to declare the tags the template uses (since i know what template i load) to avoid replacements that would not be needed

Comment: On-topic: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, this could efficiently be done by using `sed`, but I like my *inline document* way in my [*compatible answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30539879/1765658)...

Comment: @F.Hauri, the linked wiki page does not restrict itself to `sed`, but also suggests the heredoc approach (and has for years; at present, last edit is late 2010). That said, the `sed` approach is certainly preferable from a security perspective (if one doesn't trust the template author to run arbitrary code).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right! I'm not really ok with my 1st answer. I've edited them for adding a note about security and a sed version!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Security tips

This don't take care of *security issues*! Using `eval` is *evil*!

The *compatible answer* is not better!

Of course, you have to be confident about the content of your template!!

If else, try using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)! (see my last answer)

#### Quick way [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) only!:

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) you can simply:

```
eval "INSTALLPATH='/somepath/somewhere' SITEURL='example.com' PHPSERV='127.0.0.1:9000'; echo \"$(<template)\""
```

or

```
eval "INSTALLPATH='/somepath/somewhere'
    SITEURL='example.com'
    PHPSERV='127.0.0.1:9000';
    echo \"$(<template)\""
```

As you're using `eval`, you could store your resulting config file into one variable:

```
eval "INSTALLPATH='/somepath/somewhere'
    SITEURL='example.com'
    PHPSERV='127.0.0.1:9000';
    cfgBody=\"$(<template)\""
```

Then

```
echo "$cfgBody"
```

and/or

```
echo "$cfgBody" >/cfgpath/cfgfile
```

#### Doing this into a loop

```
tmplBody="$(<template)"
while read INSTALLPATH SITEURL PHPSERV CFGFILE;do
    [ "$CFGFILE" ] && eval "echo \"$tmplBody\"" >"$CFGFILE"
  done <<<"
    /somepath/somewhere            example.com  127.0.0.1:9000  /tmp/file1
    '/some\ other\ path/elsewhere' sample2.com  127.0.0.1:9001  /tmp/file2
"
```

**Note:** On second line, there are *escaped* spaces (prepanded with a backshash `\` **and** quotes `'`. The **backslash** tell `read` to not split the variable, and the quotes have to be added into the resulting `/tmp/file2`.

#### Soft way (compatible answer)

Under [posix](/questions/tagged/posix) [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), you may do this way:

```
#!/bin/sh

(
    cat <<eohead
    #!/bin/sh
    INSTALLPATH='/somepath/somewhere'
    SITEURL='example.com'
    PHPSERV='127.0.0.1:9000';
    cat <<eof
eohead
    cat template
    echo eof
) | /bin/sh
```

This don't require bash, was tested under [dash](/questions/tagged/dash) and [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox).

#### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) Without *eval* !

```
sedcmd=''
for var in INSTALLPATH SITEURL PHPSERV;do
    printf -v sc 's/${%s}/%s/;' $var "${!var//\//\\/}"
    sedcmd+="$sc"
  done
sed -e "$sedcmd" <template
```

Could work into a loop:

```
while read INSTALLPATH SITEURL PHPSERV CFGFILE;do
    if  [ "$CFGFILE" ] ;then
        sedcmd=''
        for var in INSTALLPATH SITEURL PHPSERV;do
            printf -v sc 's/${%s}/%s/;' $var "${!var//\//\\/}"
            sedcmd+="$sc"
          done
        sed -e "$sedcmd" <template >"$CFGFILE"
      fi
  done <<<"
    /somepath/somewhere             example.com  127.0.0.1:9000  /tmp/file1
    '/some\ other\ path/elsewhere'  sample2.com  127.0.0.1:9001  /tmp/file2
"
```

#### Compatible answer, using `sed`

This could work without so called *bashisms*, into a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read INSTALLPATH SITEURL PHPSERV CFGFILE;do

    sedcmd="s|\\\${INSTALLPATH}|${INSTALLPATH}|;"
    sedcmd="${sedcmd}s|\\\${SITEURL}|${SITEURL}|;"
    sedcmd="${sedcmd}s|\\\${PHPSERV}|${PHPSERV}|;"

    sed -e "$sedcmd" template >"$CFGFILE"

  done <<eof
    /somepath/somewhere             example.com  127.0.0.1:9000  /tmp/file1
    '/some\ other\ path/elsewhere'  sample2.com  127.0.0.1:9001  /tmp/file2
eof
```

Comparing outputs:

```
diff -u99 /tmp/file{1,2}
--- /tmp/file1        2015-05-31 11:02:03.407463963 +0200
+++ /tmp/file2        2015-05-31 11:02:03.407463963 +0200
@@ -1,22 +1,22 @@
 server {
     listen 80;
-    root /somepath/somewhere;
-    server_name example.com;
+    root '/some other path/elsewhere';
+    server_name sample2.com;

     client_max_body_size 20m;
     client_body_timeout 120s;

     location / {
         try_files /public/router.php =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
-        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
+        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
         fastcgi_index router.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }

     location /assets {
         try_files /app/$uri =404;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Since I use those variables elsewhere, I've changed it to just `eval echo "\"$(<template)\""` which also appears to handle it correctly. But, since I am using bash for other parts, then if bash was cleaner, then it worked better.

Comment: Note: the *shebang* `/bin/sh` after `cat <<eohead` is useless, but I find this clearer.